# Not able to upload a package

Tags: appexchange

I am not able to upload the package...What could be the potential cause of the problem? Everytime, I hit upload, I get the internal server error.

An internal server error has occurred
An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!

Comment: Could it be one of these issues? http://codequirk.blogspot.com/2013/02/managed-package-unknown-server-errors.html

Comment: Try "compiling all code" in Apex Classes. If that fails, you'd get an error (and is probably the most common error to experience).